# Missing files after installing package on NGINX Docker image

Tags: debian, apt, docker, dpkg

I'm installing the `fcgiwrap` package on the `nginx` Docker image (based on Debian Bullseye), and some files seem to be missing. This is probably something obvious, but I can't find an explanation, here is everything I tried:

#### 1. Building a Docker image with the package

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -q install -y \
    fcgiwrap \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

After running (i.e. `docker run -it my-image /bin/bash`), if I list `/usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap` I can only see a `copyright` file and empty `examples` folder.

#### 2. Run base image and install directly

`docker run -it nginx /bin/bash` then `apt install fcgiwrap`, files still missing.

#### 3. Run base image and install with `dpkg`

`docker run -it nginx /bin/bash` then:

1. `apt-get install -d fcgiwrap`
2. `cd /var/cache/apt/archives`, shows:

```
fcgiwrap_1.1.0-12_amd64.deb    libfcgi0ldbl_2.4.2-2_amd64.deb  partial
libfcgi-bin_2.4.2-2_amd64.deb  lock                            spawn-fcgi_1.6.4-2_amd64.deb
```

3. `dpkg --contents fcgiwrap_1.1.0-12_amd64.deb`, shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./etc/init.d/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      7231 2016-07-09 22:42 ./etc/init.d/fcgiwrap
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./lib/systemd/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./lib/systemd/system/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       273 2018-12-09 15:58 ./lib/systemd/system/fcgiwrap.service
-rw-r--r-- root/root       114 2018-12-09 15:58 ./lib/systemd/system/fcgiwrap.socket
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/sbin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     26776 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/sbin/fcgiwrap
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       825 2016-07-09 20:50 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/README.Debian
-rw-r--r-- root/root      3018 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1483 2017-08-05 16:19 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/copyright
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/examples/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       501 2016-07-09 22:42 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/examples/default
-rw-r--r-- root/root       229 2016-07-09 20:04 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/examples/monitrc
-rw-r--r-- root/root       648 2016-07-09 20:04 ./usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/examples/nginx.conf
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/man/man8/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1785 2018-12-09 15:58 ./usr/share/man/man8/fcgiwrap.8.gz
```

4. `dpkg -i spawn-fcgi_1.6.4-2_amd64.deb`
5. `dpkg -i libfcgi0ldbl_2.4.2-2_amd64.deb`
6. `dpkg -i fcgiwrap_1.1.0-12_amd64.deb`
7. `ls /usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/` shows:

```
copyright  examples
```

8. `cat /usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/README.Debian` shows:

```
cat: /usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/README.Debian: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I asked too early, it looks like some Docker images disable installing documentation by default, using rules similar to these: https://askubuntu.com/a/541061, in the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker`.